# Java cleanup step

Tags: java, exit-code

In java I remember there was some method you could override to be called when the jvm exits or a class is destroyed, almost like some cleanup step? I cant seem to find what it was called anywhere.Anybody know what it is called, I just cant find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a [shutdown hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html) that will be called when the JVM terminates via [`Runtime.addShutdownHook()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Shutdown hooks are not guaranteed to run if the JVM exits abnormally though.

As @Kaleb points out, you can overload `Object.finalize()` which will be called when an object is eligible for garbage collection.  As Josh Bloch points out in [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) Item 7:

> Finalizers are unpredictable, often dangerous and generally unnecessary

followed a little lower by (emphasis by Josh):

> It can take arbitrarily long between the time that an object becomes unreachable and the time that its finalizer is executed ... **never do anything time-critical in a finalizer.**

If you need to clean up resources in a class, do it in a finally block or implement a `close` method (or similar) instead of relying on `finalize()`.

Comment: You suggested implementing a close method, you mean that this has to be called explicitly then? I do in fact have such a method, if that is what you mean, however I would just like to include another check in the finalize method to make sure, say, if the close mehtod was not called as it should be. I am working with a database so making sure a connection is closed is important, especially in the long run. At least that is my thinking ?

Comment: The problem with finalize is that there is no guarantee as to how soon it will run after an object is eligible for garbage collection.  It could leave database connections open for a very long time, which could empty your connection pool of available connections and stop access to your database.  You are much better served using an API that will handle these resources for you, for example [spring jdbc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate).

Comment: I get what your saying, I'll go check spring jdbc out, but its for a project, so I need to write it myself from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

The [finalize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) method is called when an object gets destroyed.